# discord.py: RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

```
for filename in os.listdir("./cogs"):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        Bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
        Bot.run(TOKEN)
```

error:
main.py:259: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
Bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Answer (score 0):

Read the error. It says you're not awaiting a coroutine, and if you look at your code you're indeed not awaiting it.

> coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited

The migration guide explains how to load extensions in 2.0: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous